GEE applying raster Mask misses pixels and won't align with target image
I am trying to mask an image in GEE by a raster image.  Value 1 corresponds to presence of trees and 0 absence in a 30x30 resolution. However, all pixels are masked when they shouldn,'t, as I inspected some smaller areas and found some spots where they should certainly remain.
Looking at the results at small scale (see attached picture), it looks that the mask pixels are unaligned. I've tried to reproject the mask in QGIS to the image CRS, and also within GEE. In QGIS I haven't warped to the image specific extension as I plan to do this dynamically for several images with different extensions.

Here's the code link and asset links:
CODE https://code.earthengine.google.com/24f438c95f96ed0a785dd403b1c52bbe
ASSET 1 https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/preprocesado-guillesrf/assets/valdelacasa_point
ASSET 2 https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/preprocesado-guillesrf/assets/tree_mask_30
ASSET 3 https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/preprocesado-guillesrf/assets/tree_mask_proj32630_30
And also here:
Map.setCenter(-5.95108, 39.95972, 13); //WEST SPAIN

var testImage = ee.Image('LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2/LE07_202032_20020515');

var RGBvis = {bands:['SR_B4', 'SR_B3', 'SR_B2'],min: 0,max: 3000,gamma: 1.4,};

// CREATING A BUFFER FOR THE AOI
var buffer_m = 500;
function collection_buffer(featureCollection) {
  return featureCollection.map(function(feature) {
    return feature.buffer(buffer_m);
  });
}
var aoi_buffer = collection_buffer(aoi,buffer_m);
Map.addLayer(aoi_buffer ,{},'aoi_buffer'+buffer_m);
print(aoi_buffer,'aoi_buffer');

//Visualize the tree mask
Map.addLayer(treemask_30,{},'Whole tree mask');
print(treemask_30,'treemask_30');

//Rescale the image
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  //var thermalBand = image.select(thermal).multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true);
}  
var reescaled = applyScaleFactors(testImage);

//ATTEMPT 1 
function treemask (image,mask) {
  var treeMask = mask.eq(0);
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.');
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
      .updateMask(treeMask);
}
var maskedImage1 = treemask(reescaled,treemask_30);
print (maskedImage1,'maskedImage1');
Map.addLayer(maskedImage1,RGBvis,'maskedimage1');

//ATTEMPT 2
// treemask was reprojected in QGIS before loading
var maskedImage2 = treemask(reescaled,treemask_30_reproj);
print (maskedImage2,'maskedImage2');
Map.addLayer(maskedImage2,RGBvis,'maskedimage2');

//ATTEMPT 3
//This time I try to reproject and align treemask before applying it
var targetProjection = reescaled.select(0).projection();
var treemask_30_aligned = treemask_30.reproject({
  crs: targetProjection.crs(),
  scale: targetProjection.nominalScale()
}).resample('bicubic'); // Resample to match the target resolution;

var maskedImage3 = treemask(reescaled, treemask_30_aligned);
print (maskedImage3,'maskedImage3');
Map.addLayer(maskedImage3,RGBvis,'maskedimage3');

How can I mask the image properly without losing any pixel?
